# Connecting crystal report ot sql server using cakephp

Tags: sql-server, cakephp, crystal-reports

I am new to cakephp. Currently I'm trying to retrieve crystal report by connecting to  sql server using cakephp. I found a problem where my login to my DB failed because of my localhost port number is 1433. is there other option for me to retrieve my crystal report using sql server.

```
SetLogOnInfo('.\SQLEXPRESS', 'mes', 'sa', 'abc135');
```

Comment: Please show your CakePHP code for connecting to the database. Also, specifically which version of CakePHP are you using?

Comment: I managed to solve it thanks buddy.